# Ruby equivalent to 'which'

Tags: ruby

Can ruby lookup path to a binary like in bash or gnu makefile?

#### Makefile

```
which node
```

#### bash

```
user@host:~$ which node
```

### Answer thanks Senthess

#### ruby

*needs some code cleanup*

```
def which(*args)
  ret = []
  args.each{ |bin|
    possibles = ENV["PATH"].split( File::PATH_SEPARATOR )
    possibles.map {|p| File.join( p, bin ) }.find {|p|  ret.push p if File.executable?(p) } 
  }
  ret
end
```

usage

```
which 'fakebin', 'realbin', 'realbin2'
=> /full/path/realbin
=> /full/path/realbin2
```

Actually which returns one line for each.  This returns an array rather than a string, maybe better, maybe not.

see answer below for *which* that checks [single input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624348/ruby-equivalent-to-which/6624392#6624392)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Something like this:

```
def which(binary)
   ENV["PATH"].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR).find {|p| File.exists?( File.join( p, binary ) ) }
end
```

Explanation:

We access the variable `PATH`, and we split it according to the platform separator ( `:` for Unix systems, `;` for Windows ). This will yield an array of paths. We then search for the first having a file with name matching the one provided as an argument.

EDIT: If you want the full path, here's another way of implementing it:

```
def which(binary)
   possibles = ENV["PATH"].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)
   possibles.map {|p| File.join( p, binary ) }.find {|p| File.exists?(p) && File.executable?(p) }
end
```

EDIT2: updated original code to add executable check. You could implement it like this:

```
def which_multiple(*args)
    args.map {|e| which(e)}
end
```

Comment: Thats the only thing that came to mind, thanks for the tip on FILE::PATH_SEPARATOR!

Comment: Just being pedantic, technically it should return the entire path including the binary.  How about this:
def which( binary )\n
  path = ENV["PATH"] ....\n
  File.join( path, binary ) if path\n
end

Comment: One last things, promise.  bash which can take multiple bin paths, returning the first one it finds which notabin realbin => /full/path/realbin.  I wrote something, but I have to always pass an array into which for it to work

Comment: You need to check the executable flag on the file, because the existence is not enough in the path `File.exists?(p) && File.executable?(p)`

Comment: Maybe you could separate it into 2 functions? Keep the which as it is, and create a which_multiple, that will call the original which?

Comment: Not sure, it may be better to preserve the original functionality.  I think separating it into two functions would be better for readability though.

Comment: It's your choice completely :)